# How to add react to a my express API?

Tags: reactjs, express

I'm currently experimenting with Node/Express and I have so far created a very simple rest api.

My question is, now I am wanting to add React to the project and I am unable to find out how to do this effectively with keeping the MVC structure. I can't seem to find anything simple.

Any help/ tutorial guidance would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for Server Side Rendering. Redux community has a excellent guide about SSR. React Universal App (SSR base app ) has some complexity regarding API call because life-cycle hook are not called during server side rendering. Find more [here](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/docs/recipes/ServerRendering.md)